# WPF:How to Interaction.Triggers Add Where

Tags: c#, wpf

```
  <StackPanel>
      <TextBox Text="" x:Name="input"/>
      <Button Content="Click">
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"><!-- TextBox has to contain "ABC" to get Button Click enabled this event-->
                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnAdd}" CommandParameter="1"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
              </i:EventTrigger>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"><!-- TextBox has to contain "123" to get Button Click enabled this event-->
                   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnAdd2}" CommandParameter="1"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
               </i:EventTrigger>

          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </Button>
  </StackPanel>
```

I want the `<i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">` TextBox has to contain "ABC" to get Button Click enabled this event

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you want the button to be enabled only if the text inside the TextBox named input is "ABC" ?

Comment: I think he wants to say : TextBox has to contain "ABC" to get Button  Click enabled

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do this handling within your OnAdd Command. Look especially for the CanExecute Method. This one handles if you Button will be enabled or not. You can read here how to implement this :

[Commands Tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands)

Comment: Yes, from his latest edit, the OP has no choice but to use CanExecute. Just remember to RaiseCanExecuteChanged on the command on the correct properties setters.